# Click-event gets disabled after 2 clicks

Tags: jquery, cookies, click

I am currently working on an assignment where I have to show a shopping list for a certain dish. When a user clicks an item, it has to be stored in a cookie.

To be able to add items to the shopping list without having to alter my jQuery, I wrote a loop.
It works fine and I can store and unset the cookies, however, I can only click the items twice. If the item is already stored and I then delete the cookie, I can only click the list item once.

HTML

```
<section class="ingredients cd-scrolling-bg">
    <div class="container12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column6">
                <h1>Ingredienten</h1>
                <p>Om heerlijke varkenswangetjes klaar te maken, hebt u de volgende ingrediënten nodig. Klik/tik de ingrediënten aan als u ze heeft aangekocht of al in huis hebt.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">2 uien</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">1 teentje look</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">1 bruine boterham</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">2 eetlepels pittige graantjesmosterd</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">2 eetlepels bruine suiker</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">4 flesjes Sint-Bernardus Abt 12</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">Bakboter</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">1 bouquet garni</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">1 kruidnagel</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">peper</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">zout</li>
                    <li class="ingredient-item">1 kg ontvliesde varkenswangen</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JQUERY

```
var listCount = $('.ingredients ul li').length;
var i;
$('.ingredients ul li').each(function(i){
    i++;
    $(this).attr('id', 'ingredient-'+(i));
    $('#ingredient-'+(i)).on('click', function(){
        $.cookie("ingredient-"+(i), $(this).html(), {expires: 1000});
        $("#ingredient-"+(i)).on('click', function(){
            $('#ingredient-'+(i)).removeClass("strike");
            $.cookie("ingredient-"+(i), null);
        });
    });
    if($.cookie("ingredient-"+(i))){
        $("#ingredient-"+(i)).addClass("strike");
        $("#ingredient-"+(i)).on('click', function(){
            $('#ingredient-'+(i)).removeClass("strike");
            $.cookie("ingredient-"+(i), null);
        });
     }
    if(i>=12){
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have no idea what might be causing it... I didn't make a CodePen because I guess it won't save cookies and stuff... I don't know if it's important, but I'm using the cookie plugin by Klaus Hartl (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: You have a click function inside a click function. It looks like the second click function is overriding the first click function.

Comment: It is quite hard to understand logic behind this code, especially why you are binding two identical handlers. FYI, cookie works on codepen/jsfiddle the same way as on any site

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip. I will be rewriting this code entirely. Thanks for pointing out some things.